# How do you make an if-statement permanent?

Tags: javascript

I'm rather new to programming, and as a mini project to help me get better with JavaScript, I'm making a sun set. The background starts blue, and at a certain point, the background has to turn black, and I did most of this, I just don't know how to make it permenantly black.

```
   noStroke();

   // Original y position of the sun
   var sunPosition = 50;

   function draw() {

   // Draw sky
   background("skyblue");

   // Move the sun down
   sunPosition = sunPosition + 1;

   if(sunPosition === 348){
    background("black");
   }

   // Draw sun
   fill("yellow");
   ellipse(350,sunPosition,50,50);

   // Draw grass
   fill("green");
   rect(0,300,400,100);
   }
```

Comment: if(sunPosition >= 348){

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ? if @cmprogram solution didn't work for you

Answer (score 4):

You could try changing this line:
`if(sunPosition === 348){`

to this:
`if(sunPosition >= 348){`

to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a great way to learn. Kudos.

I assume the code that you have posted is running within a loop of some kind. Each iteration of the loop increments the `sunPosition`.

However you're only checking that `sunPosition` is exactly equal to `348`.

Instead, check whether it's greater than or equal to `348`.

```
if(sunPosition >= 348){
  background("black");
}
```

Or, you can stop the loop here somehow.

```
if(sunPosition === 348){
  background("black");
  stopLoopSomehow();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a mutable variable, like your `sunPosition`, to store whether the sun has already set:

```
// Original y position of the sun
var sunPosition = 50;
// Original color of sky
var skyColor = "skyblue";

function draw() {
    // Move the sun down
    sunPosition = sunPosition + 1;
    // check for sunset
    if (sunPosition === 348) {
        skyColor = "black";
    }

    // Draw sky
    background(skyColor);
    // Draw sun
    fill("yellow");
    ellipse(350,sunPosition,50,50);
    // Draw grass
    fill("green");
    rect(0,300,400,100);
}
```

Alternatively (and more robust, as you don't need to exactly hit the change condition), is to compute the sky color on every `draw` call, depending on the sun position:

```
function draw() {
    // Move the sun down
    sunPosition = sunPosition + 1;

    // Draw sky
    if (sunPosition >= 348) {
        background("skyblue");
    } else {
        background("black");
    }
    // Draw sun
    fill("yellow");
    ellipse(350,sunPosition,50,50);
    // Draw grass
    fill("green");
    rect(0,300,400,100);
}
```

With the `if`/`else`, it'll become clear why you want to use `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that an if statement simply runs a check, and if the check within the parentheses returns true, the block proceeding it is executed, otherwise it continues.

So with the code :

```
if(sunPosition === 348){
    background("black");
   }
```

This will return true, only when sunPosition is exactly equal to 348. So let's look into this further.

The === comparison equates to "is stricly equal to"

Which means the value on the left must be identical to the value on the right in every way.

i.e.

```
1 === 1 // True
1 === true // False
1 === "1" // False
1 === 2 // False
```

The == comparison equates to "is equal to"

Which means the value on the left should be the same as the value on the right, but it's not a strict comparison, meaning types can differ.

```
1 == 1 // True
1 == true // True
1 == "1" // True
1 == 2 // False
```

So under the assumption that your sunPosition is being moved incrementally, either by a loop or by a button click, the sunPosition will only === 348 at one specific point. Once it doesn't equal that, the block proceeding that won't run.

Using that logic, by changing your code to :

```
if(sunPosition >= 348){
    background("black");
   }
```

You are using the greater than or equal to comparison.

So as long as the sunPosition is greater than or equal to 348, the comparison will return as true, and the code in the statement following, will run.